# forms authentication web config error

Tags: .net, authentication

I am incorporating forms authentication into a new app, I have `deny users="?"` in the web.config I would like all javascript/css/images to be accessible so i included

```
 <location path="Assets">
     <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"></allow>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
```

I am receiving an error stating The element 'system.web' has invalid child element location.

I don't understand why this is being generated. Can someone explain why, and a possible fix for this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

The location element needs to be in the configuration section and not in the system.web.

the reasoning is it is part of the application configuration not how it runs.